# CSS 3 floating divs - left center middle with margin between each other

Tags: css

I am trying to make 3 floating divs - left, center and right with space (margin) between them.
for example:

div with 245px width, 6px space, div with 246px, 6px space, div with 245px (748px total).

the way I found to make it is:
container with 748px, floated left div, absolute positioned div with `margin:0 251px;` (245+6) and float right div.

it works (but not in IE6), so I want to know if there's other way without using position absolute.
I dont want to use 3 floated left divs and the middle one with margin because when u zoom out the structure is not full width. (therefore u must use 1 floated left, and 1 floated right.)

Hope you understand and can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this things in ur web page
        .mainDiv
        {
            width:748px;
            float:left;
        }
        .leftDiv{float:left;width:245px;padding-right:6px;}
        .centerDiv{float:left;width:246px;padding-right:6px;}
        .rightDiv{float:right;width:245px;}

use this stysheet for ur div structure
give class name as in stylesheet

Comment: padding is the same like margin but changes the div width/height - doesnt help.

Comment: yes bcz once u fix width of main div than u have to calculate your child div width + padding/margin and it must less or equal to parent div width

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS grid system.

Examples are http://cssgrid.net/ or others like http://960.gs, Twitter Bootstrap, Blueprint CSS.. take your pick.

Twitter Bootstrap, for instance, has support for both fixed width layouts and fluid layouts.
CSSGrid, on the other hand, scales really well when you re-dimension the browser window.

You can learn how to work with a grid rather quickly, and it will help you imensely in keeping your layout clean.